# I want to show live output of my discord bot on a website

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

This is bot code:

```
const discord = require("discord");
const commands = require("discord.ext");

const client = commands.Bot(
  (command_prefix = "!"),
  (intents = discord.Intents.default())
);
const requests = require("requests");

// This is a list of the commands that the bot knows
const availableCommands = ["!hello", "!goodbye", "!help"];

client.listen(async (message) => {
  // If the message is from the bot itself, ignore it
  if (message.author === client.user) {
    return;
  }
  if (message.content.startsWith("!hello")) {
    await message.channel.send("Hello!");
  } else if (message.content.startsWith("!goodbye")) {
    await message.channel.send("Goodbye!");
  } else if (message.content.startsWith("!log")) {
    console.log("Goodbye!");
  } else if (message.content.startsWith("!help")) {
    // Build the response message
    let response = "Commands:\n";
    for (const command of commands) {
      response += `${command}\n`;
    }
    response += "\nBot made by Agent_12";
    await message.channel.send(response);
  }

  // Send the message to the server
  requests.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/terminal-output",
    (json = { output: message.content })
  );
});

client.run(
  "bot token"
);
```

This is website code::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- HTML code for the webpage -->

    <div id="terminal-output"></div>

    <style>
      /* CSS code to style the webpage */

      #terminal-output {
        font-family: monospace;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      // JavaScript code to retrieve the terminal output from the server and display it on the webpage

      async function displayTerminalOutput() {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/terminal-output");
        const output = await response.text();
        document.getElementById("terminal-output").innerHTML = output;
      }

      // Update the terminal output every second
      setInterval(displayTerminalOutput, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is server code:

```
// Node.js code for the server

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// This is a list of the commands that the bot knows
const commands = ["!hello", "!goodbye", "!help"];

app.post("/terminal-output", (req, res) => {
  terminalOutput = req.body.output;
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get("/terminal-output", (req, res) => {
  res.send(getTerminalOutput());
});

app.use(express.static("C:\\Users\\shahe\\Desktop\\test"));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port 3000");
});

function getTerminalOutput() {
  // Return the output that you want to display on the webpage
  return "Hello, World!";
}
```

I tried everything but i cant figure it out. Something keeps going wrong and the output just wont show
Please help me if you can i am using express.js to do this. i am sending the console to the server and then the server is going to send it to the website from where it will be displayed. i tried python for the bot but doesnt work so switched to javascript.

Comment: Why does this have the `python-2.7` label and the `discord.py` label?

Comment: where does it have those labels?

Comment: They were deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using express json for api I would use websockets with sockets.io there are some good videos about it like from fireship https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BfCnjr_Vjg in conjunction with the discord js api to send the discord messages to the site in real time